# Chef - Different files for different environments

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to Chef and I am working on environments to output different files for different environments. For example, I want to load a different robots.txt and .htaccess file for either staging or productions environments.

I found the code below from a website but am unsure how to accomplish what i am trying to do. Can this be done in a .erb file or does this have to live in an .rb file?

```
if node.chef_environment == 'development' do
#
# do not configure basic auth
#
else
#
#  configure basic auth
#
end
```

Also, how would I be able to dynamically change content in files instead of having to create a completely separate file. For instance, a link in a js file I want to change depending on the environment. Can that be done through a variable somewhere?

Comment: If you really just want to change a small part of a file, that's best done with a `.erb` file. As I mention in my answer, this can be very messy. I consider it a bad idea to put your project code (such as html, js, server-scripting files) in Chef itself; I prefer to use a source control system for that (such as git or svn).

Comment: I appreciate all the help you have given me, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: By the way, I am using git for source control but need to have some parts of js, php, etc. files to be dynamic when it comes to which environment is created

Comment: That is a tricky situation that I've not found a smooth solution with Chef. For links within the environment, it's best to use relative paths For links that traverse between services (e.g. website to API), you need an environment specific proxy server (e.g. Apache or Nginx with rewrite rules) to avoid having to have your source code be riddled with environment-aware `.erb` files.

Comment: thanks again, everything is working out as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do it either way, but I would do it with an `.rb` file. If you had a `.htaccess.erb` file, it would be very congested with all your different environment code mingled together - harder to read/diagnose.

I find it much cleaner to have a cookbook dedicated to environment setup, have it's recipes detect the environment and grab all your configuration files from different places within the cookbook. You would be using the [`cookbook_file`](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_cookbook_file.html), [`remote_directory`](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_remote_directory.html) or [`remote_file`](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_remote_file.html) resources for this.

Here is a decent example from the `cookbook_file` resource that detects the platform. You should be able to adapt it to detect the environment and source location of the file instead of the destination path.

```
cookbook_file "application.pm" do
  path case node['platform']
    when "centos","redhat"
      "/usr/lib/version/1.2.3/dir/application.pm"
    when "arch"
      "/usr/share/version/core_version/dir/application.pm"
    else
      "/etc/version/dir/application.pm"
    end
  source "application-#{node['languages']['perl']['version']}.pm"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
end
```

Something like this might work well for you:

```
cookbook_file ".htaccess" do
  path "/var/www/"
  source "apache/#{node['chef_environment'].htaccess"
  owner "apache"
  group "apache"
  mode "0400"
end
```

This *should* (I'm rusty and haven't Chef'ed in a while) create a file named `.htaccess` copied from `/<cookbook_directory>/files/apache/development.htaccess` on nodes in the development environment, and copied from `/<cookbook_directory>/files/apache/production.htaccess` on nodes in the production environment. Thus each file is clearly named and free from any logic - less likely to make any mistakes.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about different environments(Dev, QA, Production) not about different Platforms(Debian, RHEL)

Comment: @charlesbabbage agreed. The first code block is a copy/paste example from the link. The 2nd code block is adapting it to use the environment instead of the platform.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. As for the robots.txt file, will something like this work as well? Im not sure if I can create that from a .rb file as well since it is a different file format.

Comment: Sure, you can source `robots.txt` the same way. The point of this approach is that the files you're copying are their own formats (`.htaccess`, `.txt` both being plaintext) without any ruby code or template markup in them. Although you probably don't need to have different `robots.txt` files for different environments - your non-prod environments should be isolated from crawlers by different means, I should hope.

Answer (score 0):

You could use templates that will config and other files with the correct parameters for your specific environment.  For example, this is my template for creating /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-* files:

```
#
# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<%= @interface %>
#
# Generated by Chef for <%= node['hostname'] %>
#
<%= @interface %>
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
<%= @hwaddr %>
<%= @ipaddress %>
<%= @netmask %>
<%= @broadcast %>
<%= @master %>
<%= @slave %>
```

Here's my recipe code to populate the variables.  Recipe has no idea about actual values, just about the infrastructure setup, i.e. there are environments and there are different subnets within one particular environment:

```
getMac = {}

# Get "physical" interfaces
node['network']['interfaces'].keys.sort.each do |iface|
    if node['network']['interfaces'][iface]['encapsulation'] == 'Ethernet' and
        node['network']['interfaces'][iface]['type'] != 'bond'
        node['network']['interfaces'][iface]['addresses'].keys.each do |address|
            if node['network']['interfaces'][iface]['addresses'][address]['family'] == 'lladdr'
                getMac[iface]=address
            end
        end
    end
end
ip = node['network']['address'][node['hostname']]
env = 'dot' + ip.split('.')[2]
netmask = "NETMASK=" + node['network'][env]['netmask']
broadcast = "BROADCAST=" + node['network'][env]['broadcast']

node['network']['interfaces'].keys.sort.each do |iface|
    if node['network']['interfaces'][iface]['encapsulation'] == 'Ethernet' and 
        node['network']['interfaces'][iface]['type'] != 'bond'
        # find the non-primary interface, which is not one of eth0, em1, or eno1[0-9]*
        # Otherwise, leave IP/netmask/broadcast as assigned above
        if !iface.match(/ens16|eno1|eth0|em1/)
            ipaddress = ''
            netmask = ''
            broadcast = ''
        else
            ipaddress = "IPADDR=" + ip
        end
        template "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-#{iface}" do
            source "ifcfg-iface.erb"
            mode 0644
            owner "root"
            group "root"
            variables({
                :interface => "DEVICE=#{iface}",
                :ipaddress => ipaddress, 
                :netmask => netmask,
                :broadcast => broadcast,
                :hwaddr => "HWADDR=#{getMac['iface']}",
            })  
        end 
    end
end
```

Here's the environment file:

```
override_attributes ({
    'network' => {
        # one environment can use multiple subnets
        'dotX' => {
            'broadcast' => "a.b.X.255",
            'gateway' => "a.b.X.1",
            'netmask' => "255.255.255.0",
        },
        # all nodes for this environment
        'address' => {
            'hostname' => "a.b.X.d",
        },
    },
})
```